# How can I resolve the 'Invalid column name 'Discriminator'' error when extending and inheriting a BaseClass in EF with an additional SomeMap table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've been refactoring some code and can't get past an EF error. I have a BaseClass that I have largely replicated across a bunch of different projects, with the difference being that a few of these projects have an additional SomeMap table that foreign keys to the BaseClass. So my goal was to move the BaseClass to a library that the projects would simply reference, and extend it with the SomeMap only for those projects that need it, and so remove the ICollection property from the BaseClass implementation in the library. Here is a very simplified version (probably not even compilable..) of what is going on. This is what the BaseClass used to look like:

```
public partial class BaseClass
{

    public BaseClass(){}

    public int baseID {get; set;}

    public int otherID {get; set;}

    public string someName {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<SomeMap> SomeMap {get; set;}

}
```

This is what the map table looked like, with baseID foreign keyed to the base table:

```
public partial class SomeMap
{

    public SomeMap(){}

    public int mapID {get; set;}

    public int someOtherID {get; set;}

    public int baseID {get; set;}

    public double someValue {get; set;}

    public virtual BaseClass BaseClass {get; set;}

}
```

So, basically what I did was remove the SomeMap ICollection<> from the BaseClass that is now in a referenced dll, and then add to the SomeMap class, resulting in this:

```
public partial class SomeMap
{

    public SomeMap(){}

    public int mapID {get; set;}

    public int someOtherID {get; set;}

    public int baseID {get; set;}

    public double someValue {get; set;}

    public virtual BaseClassExt BaseClass {get; set;}
}

public partial class BaseClassExt : BaseClass
{
    public virtual ICollection<SomeMap> SomeMap {get; set;}
}
```

In my OnModelCreating override method (in my project, not the dll) I have the following fluid API call:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClassExt>().HasMany(t => t.SomeMap).WithRequired(t => t.BaseClass).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I've tried just about every solution I can find on here, including adding the [NotMapped] attribute to the new extension class (doesn't seem to allow this to work), and also various other fluid API calls to try to explicitly define the foreign key relationship in alternative ways. Everything results in some variation of the error:

'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. Inner Exception SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.'

whenever I try to start pulling and processing data with things like object.SomeMap.Where(t => t.BaseClass.someName == someName_)...  etc, etc

Thanks

**Update**

I can make *slight* progress by adding the following to the OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>().Map(t => t.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(0));
```

However, this just results in a different error message:

'Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 14, 34: EntityTypes BaseClass, BaseClassExt are being mapped to the same rows in table BaseClass. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to figure this out, so here's the answer so none of you also waste days of your life...

In addition to the fluid API call I mentioned above, you need a few more to resolve duplicate mapping errors. So in the end, your OnModelCreating() needs to look like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>().Map(t => 
        t.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(0));

    modelBuilder.Ignore<BaseClass>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeMap>().ToTable("BaseClass");
}
```